# Apply mask in a input field when the field already has a value

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

How can I apply a [mask](http://plugins.jquery.com/mask/) in a `<input type='text' />` when the field already has a value ?

Example:
`<input type='text' ng-model='contact.Cep' />`

When the page is rendered, the field has the correct value, but withou mask, I need put the focus on this field, and then press any key (like space bar) to make the mask format the field

**Mask**

`angular.element("my-field").mask("99999-999")`

In JQuery should be 
`$("#my-field").mask("99999-999")`

Answer (score 0):

Apply it like this:

```
<input id="myfield" type="text" value='10071985'></input>
$("#myfield").mask("99999-999");
```

It works fine.